# how to update table with join and case in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have problem when update may table

```
    UPDATE FGJ
SET  
     [base_title]=
                        case when NL.[atypcode_type] = 105 THEN NL.[ATYPCODE] 
                        ELSE 0
                    END ,
     [base_mande]= 
                        case when  NL.[atypcode_type] = 105 and NL.[ATYPCODE]=FGJ.[base_title] 
                        THEN NL.[mande]+FGJ.[base_mande]
                        ELSE 0.00
                    END 
                    ,....



from [dbo].[SuratMali_FinalGozareshJame] FGJ
INNER JOIN #tmp_notLinked NL 
       ON FGJ.CodeL = NL.[codelfinal]
```

this code not work for update table
thanks for read my problem

Comment: `case` can be avoided if you split the `update`

Comment: How can I write it without the case, i have many columns and for update must check [atypcode_type] and  NL.[ATYPCODE]=FGJ.[base_title]

Comment: If its not working you need to explain in what way its not working. If you get error messages, add those error messages to your question. If you get the wrong results, add example data to the question, so we can replicate your problem (including what the tables started like, what the update did, what the update should have done, and an explanation of why it djoukd have done that.)

Answer (score 0):

The `CASE` can be avoided it you split your update into two updates

```
UPDATE FGJ
SET  
     [base_title]= NL.[ATYPCODE] -- however, this case had different condition in your original query!
     [base_mande]= NL.[mande]+FGJ.[base_mande]
FROM [SuratMali_FinalGozareshJame] FGJ
INNER JOIN #tmp_notLinked NL 
       ON FGJ.CodeL = NL.[codelfinal]
WHERE NL.[atypcode_type] = 105 and NL.[ATYPCODE] = FGJ.[base_title] 


UPDATE FGJ
SET  
     [base_title]= 0 -- however, this case had different condition!
     [base_mande]= 0
FROM [SuratMali_FinalGozareshJame] FGJ
INNER JOIN #tmp_notLinked NL 
       ON FGJ.CodeL = NL.[codelfinal]
WHERE NL.[atypcode_type] != 105 or NL.[ATYPCODE] != FGJ.[base_title]
```

However, as I mention in the code your `case` conditions are different. If it is really the case (not the typo) then you have to create `update` for each condition.

It is also possible to rewrite the solution that `inner join` is not stated explicitly if you use subquery (see bellow). This solution assumes that the subquery returns just one value (for example if NL.[codelfinal] is primary key). However, the join is hidden in the syntax anyway and there is no point to rewrite it like this.

```
UPDATE FGJ
SET  
     [base_mande]= (
        SELECT NL.[mande]
        FROM #tmp_notLinked NL
        WHERE FGJ.CodeL = NL.[codelfinal] and 
              NL.[atypcode_type] = 105 and 
              NL.[ATYPCODE] = FGJ.[base_title] 
      ) + FGJ.[base_mande]
FROM [SuratMali_FinalGozareshJame] FGJ
```